# Make manual servervalidation and color textfield if failed

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to change the color of a textfield to red if a serverside validation fails.

If result is True or False nothing happens

JQuery

```
        $('.datein').change(function () {
        //send servervalidering ajax
        var data = { dateOut: $('#resource_dateout').val(), dateHourOut: $('#resource_hourout').val(), dateMinuteOut: $('#resource_minuteout').val(),
            dateIn: $('#resource_datein').val(), dateHourIn: $('#resource_hourin').val(), dateMinuteIn: $('#resource_minutein').val()
        };
        $.post("Resource/isDateValid", data, ajaxsuccess);
    });

function ajaxsuccess(result) {
    if ($('.datein').hasClass('.resourceerror')) {
        if (result == "True") {
            $('.datein').removeClass('.resourceerror');
        }
    }
    else if (result == "False") {
        $('.datein').addClass('.resourceerror');
    }
}
```

Html

```
                <span class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateIn.Date, new { @Id = "resource_datein", @class = "datepicker datein", maxlength = "10" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateIn.Hour, new { @Id = "resource_hourin", @class = "datein", maxlength = "2" })
                    :
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DateIn.Minute, new { @Id = "resource_minutein", @class = "datein", maxlength = "2" })
                </span>
                <span>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateIn.Date)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateIn.Hour)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DateIn.Minute)
                </span>
```

Is there a way I can just toggle a validation instead? My code dont work, I am 100% sure the Ajax call either returns "True" or "False"

Edit: When accessing the css classes I wrote hasClass('.classname') instead of hasClass('classname')

Comment: Could you post your CSS please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing the css classes I wrote hasClass('.classname') instead of hasClass('classname')

Answer (score 0):

Change the if(result) to if(result == "True"). Since result is the AJAX response, it is a string, and if(result) just tests to see if it has non-zero value, not if it the text of the string is "True". This MIGHT help, since if server validation fails and returns "False", your current code removes the .resourceerror class from the inputs

Comment: Updated #0 But still dont color it red if result == "False"